# Numbering issue for subparagraph: Numbering of paragraph and subparagraph are the same

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

Is there any way to fix the numbering issue for subparagraph

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

% Format section, subsection, and subsubsection titles
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Test Section}
    test
    \subsection{Test Subsection}
    test
    \subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
    test
    \paragraph{Test Modified Paragraph}
    test
    \subparagraph{Test Modified Sub-Paragraph}
    test
    
    

\end{document}
```

The output for the code:

> [image: Blockquote]

The numbering of paragraph and subparagraph are the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The numbering of paragraphs and subparagraphs is the same.

In the code block

```
\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

I suggest you change the line

```
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
```

to

```
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
```